# Eclipse CDT + MinGW + GLEW, Type undefined reference to `LoadShaders(char const*, char const*)'

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, glew

Already get one error only for `LoadShaders`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <glfw3.h>
GLFWwindow* window;

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include <common/shader.hpp>

int main( void )
{
    // Initialise GLFW
    if( !glfwInit() )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // Open a window and create its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow( 1024, 768, "Tutorial 02 - Red triangle", NULL, NULL);
    if( window == NULL ){
        fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // Initialize GLEW
    glewExperimental = true; // Needed for core profile
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_STICKY_KEYS, GL_TRUE);

    // Dark blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

    GLuint VertexArrayID;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

    // Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
    GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );


    static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = {
        -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
    };

    GLuint vertexbuffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    do{

        // Clear the screen
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

        // Use our shader
        glUseProgram(programID);

        // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(
            0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
            3,                  // size
            GL_FLOAT,           // type
            GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
            0,                  // stride
            (void*)0            // array buffer offset
        );

        // Draw the triangle !
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // 3 indices starting at 0 -> 1 triangle

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    } // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while( glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
           glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 );

    // Cleanup VBO
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
    glDeleteProgram(programID);

    // Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

I get error:

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   undefined reference to `LoadShaders(char const*, char const*)'  Opengl33.cpp    /Opengl33/src   line 63 C/C++ Problem

Library order load:

```
glew32s 
gdi32 
opengl32 
glfw3dll
```

Compiler string in console:

```
g++ -o Opengl33.exe "src\\Opengl33.o" -lglew32s -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3dll
```

(`-DGLEW_STATIC` don't help me)

I tried to google this problem, but doesn't find solution.

Comment: I don't see a definition for LoadShader here, if it is defined in common/shader.hpp then please also post this file.

Comment: #ifndef SHADER_HPP
#define SHADER_HPP

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path);

#endif   - it's all shader.hpp

Comment: sorry for format, dont understand how use [code] in comments

Answer (score 1):

When implementing methods/classes in different files, one has to compile each of them to object files and then link them together. Here, you are only linking Opengl33.o, although LoadShader is defined in shader.o. Try to change the linker line to:

```
g++ -o Opengl33.exe "src\\Opengl33.o" "common\\shader.o" -lglew32s -lgdi32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3dll
```

Although, I'm wondering why this is necessary, since you're using eclipse.

Comment: If you know, please tell me how make this in Eclipse - add to linker string "common\\shader.o" (common\\shader.hpp located in "includes" of MinGW). Sorry, I'm noob, beginning programmer.

Comment: At least in my eclipse, this is automatically done for all source files included in the project. Does the shader.cpp file get compiled?

Comment: Sorry, where I can see compiled shader.cpp or not? I must search for "shader.o"? Please, sorry again for my stupud questions...

Comment: Have a look in the Console (where you already copied the linker line from). There should be a `g++ -c ....` line for each *.cpp file.

Comment: Don's see "shader.cpp" in linker string: Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o "src\\opengl33.o" "..\\src\\opengl33.cpp" 
g++ -o opengl33.exe "src\\opengl33.o" -lglew32 -lopengl32 -lglfw3dll 
src\opengl33.o: In function `main':
C:\workspace\opengl33\Debug/../src/opengl33.cpp:61: undefined reference to `LoadShaders(char const*, char const*)'  May be, I must move folder "common" to "src"? (place with opengl33.cpp)? Now "common/shader.cpp" located in "MinGW/includes"

Comment: no "shader.cpp" in linker string, only "opengl33.cpp"